# Build a disposable method at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

My program creates in anytime new methods (Using `MethodBuilder` with array of byte\IL) that it executes them once and discard the reference to them. I found that they don't actually affected by the GC. Is there a way to let the GC collect them or dispose them?

I found that the problem is that to create new method, need to load it's assembly that can't be unloaded after. I need to run those methods on the main appdomain. (It creates objects or modifying some)
Is there an alternative to `MethodBuilder` and just execute those byte\IL anyway?

Comment: What is your problem which you decided to solve using `MethodBuilder` ?

Comment: @L.B I am making a C#-Console thing that you write a line of C# code and it executes it. I can just open AppDomain and execute it there, but when I want to save the objects that the line creates, it's unavailable when I unload the AppDomain. I must unload it I need to create AppDomain per line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DynamicMethod`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx) if you only need to emit a method that can be garbage collected later. From the docs:

> Defines and represents a dynamic method that can be compiled, executed, and discarded. Discarded methods are available for garbage collection.

If you need to build a type dynamically then you need to define a dynamic assembly for it that can be collected. To do that use `AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly` with the `AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect` option. There are some restrictions on what you can do in a collectible assembly detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554932.aspx).

Comment: I tried to set array of bytes from another appdomain & assembly  (That isn't loaded to the appdomain that is trying to execute it) with the corrent signatures, and it gave it `Signature is not IMAGE_CEE_CS_CALLCONV_LOCAL_SIG` when I tried to invoke it. The method was static and I gave it `CallingConventions.Standard`.

Comment: @KugBuBu I don't know what you are trying to do or what that error means. It sounds like you have another question about how to use `DynamicMethod` in your specific scenario. If you want, send me a link to it in another comment and I will have a look at it.

Comment: If you need to build a type using Reflection.Emit, you can put it into a collectible assembly by using [`AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.assemblybuilderaccess).

Comment: @svick Interesting, I did not know about that option. I updated the answer to include that info.